# how to initialize sharedPreferences flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

In order to Authenticate to Api, I created AuthProvider class to authenticate, after getting accessToken from the Api,I stored the token using sharedPreferences,I wanted to check if the user loggedIn or not, so I initialized sharedPreferences to return a boolean value if it contains the token... as shown in the code bellow:

```
class AuthProvider with ChangeNotifier{
  
    bool _isLoading = false;
  bool get isLoading => _isLoading;
  User user = User();
  late SharedPreferences prefs ;
  
   
 String token = '';
  Map<String, String>   _mainHeaders = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
       
    };

   void updateHeader(String token) {
    _mainHeaders = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
    };
  }
  

 

Future<ResponseModel> login(String username, String password) async {
    print("Getting token");
    //print(authRepo.getUserToken().toString());
    _isLoading = true;
 
       notifyListeners();
    http.Response response = await dologin(username, password);
   
    // print('${response.body.}');
   var answer = User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
   print('the result is : ${answer.token}');
    
   print('level 1: ${response.body.toString()}');
    late ResponseModel responseModel;
    print(response.statusCode);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
         
      //authRepo.saveUserToken((response.body["token"]).toString());
       print("Backend token: ${response.body.toString()}");

     responseModel = ResponseModel(true, answer.token!);
       
    //  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    //  prefs.setString(ApiConstants.kEY_ACCESS_TOKEN, answer.token!);
      storeToken(answer.token!);

    } else {
      responseModel = ResponseModel(false, response.reasonPhrase!);
    
    }
    _isLoading = false;

       notifyListeners();
    return responseModel;
  }

  
  bool userLoggedIn() =>
      prefs.containsKey(ApiConstants.kEY_ACCESS_TOKEN) ? true : false;


  // bool clearSharedData() => authRepo.clearSharedData();

 void storeToken(String token) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setString(ApiConstants.kEY_ACCESS_TOKEN, token);
    print('the token is here : ${token}');

  }

...
```

in main.dart I created a consumer to check if the user is loggedIn or not :

```
 child: MaterialApp(
          home: Consumer<AuthProvider>(
            builder: ((context, auth, _){
              return auth.userLoggedIn() ? const  HomePage() : const loginScreen();
            })
            ),
         ...
```

when I hit run I got the following error in my console:

The following LateError was thrown building Consumer(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<AuthProvider?>]):
LateInitializationError: Field 'prefs' has not been initialized.
The relevant error-causing widget was
Consumer.
PS : I tried to initialize sharedPreferences : SharedPreferences? prefs;
the error would be:
Null check operator used on a null value.
...

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<bool> userLoggedIn() async{
      prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      prefs.containsKey(ApiConstants.kEY_ACCESS_TOKEN) ? true : false;
}
```

Change userLoggedIn getter to this.

Comment: The await expression can only be used in an async function.
Try marking the function body with either 'async' or 'async*'

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because you've marked your `prefs` as `late` but you haven't initialised it (as written in the error message). Just get rid of the line `late SharedPreferences prefs;` at the top and ensure that you initialise it each time you need it within the method. I.e. call `await SharedPreferences.getInstance();` each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function from init state and check the sharedprefrences in it like

```
late SharedPreferences prefs;

//initialize shared prefrences then access it 
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    sharedData();
  }

void sharedData() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance(); 
  }

 void storeToken(String token) async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString(ApiConstants.kEY_ACCESS_TOKEN, token);
    print('the token is here : ${token}');
  }
```

Comment: The method 'initState' isn't defined in a superclass of 'AuthProvider'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'initState' in a superclass.

Comment: write this code in main.dart file